# SSRS Permissions

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssms

I have looked on the internet and haven't been able to find anything that is straight to the point. I am using SSRS (native mode, developing reports in VS) and had a question about permissions, as I am worried I am overdoing it. We use AD groups for windows authentication for permissions to various reports on report server. Currently, the way it is set up, is permissions are granted to the server, database, and each Stored Procedure individually (via SSMS). On the report server URL, permissions are granted in site settings, folder settings, and report level.

1. Is this too much; are all these permissions required?
2. Is there a more efficient way to establish permissions?
3. Do users need access to the "Datasource" and "dataset" folders in order to run the reports?

I just want to clean up what we currently have and use best practices.Thanks in advanced!

Comment: yup all permissions are required. yeah but its up to you whether you want to give only view permission or publish , etc. To refer http://bhushan.extreme-advice.com/user-roles-and-permissions-in-ssrs/

Comment: Are you still having an issue sorting out permissions?

Answer (score 2):

I have been actively cleaning up our Report Server content and standards. So here is what I can provide based on that experience.

**Is this too much; are all these permissions required?**

*ANSWER*: Windows AD group is a good way to setup permissions to the report server. It's best to have a few folders that will contain the reports, then give the folder the needed access and allow all reports within that folder to inherit the folder security. Subfolders could have higher levels of security (we have done some of this in our reporting environment).

**Is there a more efficient way to establish permissions?**

*ANSWER*: Try to have a good vision for which folders you will need on the server, organize that information in slide deck, or Word document. Get buy-in from your management and business leaders in for the various departments.  Also, analyze any existing reporting systems and try to determine how they accommodate user access.  As far as Stored Procedure permissions it's probably best to have your DBA give stored procedure permissions using the same user that authenticates your various datasource, and to use the same user (for example "myDomain\ssrsreports).

**Do users need access to the "Datasource" and "dataset" folders in order to run the reports?**

*ANSWER*: Users do not need to access these folder. As long as the shared Data Source is authenticated by "Windows Account" or "SQL Server account" the data set that references the data source will execute for all users who can access to report.

**Further Reading...**

If you have access to Pluralsight training website there are some good videos there for SSRS. If you do not have Pluralsight subscription you can get a free 3-month trial with a Microsoft Visual Studio Dev Essentials account, which is free to create.

- [Reporting Services Report Server Administration](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/ssrs-admin/table-of-contents)
- [Reporting Services Report Development Fundamentals Part 1](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/intro-ssrs-reporting/table-of-contents)
- [Microsoft Visual Studio Dev Essentials](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/dev-essentials/)

Answer (score 0):

1. I would separate permissions by AD group/report folder. Going to the individual report level is a bit overkill.
2. I also create a few new roles for the report folders to manage who can read the reports and who owns them by folder level. In SSRS, new roles and adjustments to existing roles must be performed in SQL Server Management studio, SSMS. After opening up SSMS, click on "Connect" and select "Reporting Services…"

   [image: connect menu]

Enter your Server Name and login information and then click Connect.

[image: connect to server window]

After connecting to the Report Server, open the Security Folder right click on "Roles" and click on "New Role…"

I created 2 new roles ("Browser Group", "Functional Owner") with the same permission as "Browser".

Then on the report manager click on the down arrow for a folder and select "Security"

Then click "New Role Assignment"

Then enter the Active Directory group or an email address and check the new role you created.

You can then query the server for the permissions and show these in a report.

```
;WITH 
catalog_type_description
AS
(
    SELECT tbl.* FROM (VALUES
      ( 1, 'Folder')
    , ( 2, 'Report')
    , ( 3, 'Resource')
    , ( 4, 'Linked Report')
    , ( 5, 'Data Source')
    , ( 6, 'Report Model')
    , ( 8, 'Shared Dataset')
    , ( 9, 'Report Part')
    ) tbl ([TypeID], [TypeDescription]) 
    WHERE 
        TypeID = 1
)
, 
nonreport_folders
AS
(
    SELECT tbl.* FROM (VALUES
      ( 'Images')
    , ( 'SharedDataSets')
    , ( 'Data Sources')
    , ( '')
    ) tbl ([FolderName]) 
)
, 
reporting_role_names -- added roles to the report server
AS
(
    SELECT tbl.* FROM (VALUES
      ( 'Browser Group')
    , ( 'Functional Owner')
    ) tbl ([RoleName]) 
)
, 
user_list
AS
(
    SELECT 
          usr.[UserID]
        , usr.[UserName]
        , [UserNameFormat] = 
            CASE 
                WHEN CHARINDEX('\', usr.[UserName]) > 0 THEN UPPER(SUBSTRING(usr.[UserName] ,CHARINDEX('\', usr.[UserName]) + 1, LEN(usr.[UserName])))
                ELSE usr.[UserName] 
            END 
    FROM 
        dbo.[Users] AS usr
)
, 
reporting_roles
AS
(
    SELECT 
          cat.[Name]
        , rol.[RoleName]
        , usr.[UserNameFormat]
        , [ReportingRoleName] = rpt.[RoleName]
    FROM 
        dbo.[Catalog] AS cat
        INNER JOIN catalog_type_description AS tpd ON cat.[Type] = tpd.[TypeID] 
        LEFT JOIN dbo.PolicyUserRole AS urol ON urol.[PolicyID] = cat.[PolicyID]
        LEFT JOIN dbo.Roles AS rol ON urol.[RoleID] = rol.[RoleID]
        LEFT JOIN reporting_role_names AS rpt ON rpt.[RoleName] = rol.[RoleName]
        LEFT JOIN dbo.Policies AS pol ON urol.[PolicyID] = pol.[PolicyID]
        LEFT JOIN user_list AS usr ON urol.[UserID] = usr.[UserID]
        LEFT JOIN nonreport_folders AS nrf ON nrf.[FolderName] = cat.[Name]
    WHERE 
        1=1
        AND nrf.[FolderName] IS NULL
)
SELECT DISTINCT
      [FolderName] = rpt.[Name]
    , rpt.[RoleName]
    , [UserNameFormat] = STUFF((SELECT '; ' + rol.[UserNameFormat] FROM reporting_roles rol WHERE rol.[RoleName] = rpt.[RoleName] AND rol.[Name] = rpt.[Name] FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
    , [ReportingRoleName]
FROM 
    reporting_roles AS rpt
```

3. Users need read access to the "Datasource" and "dataset" folders. I would use an AD group such as `Domain Users` for this.

References:

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SQL-Server-Reporting-SSRS-50c4d06b

http://bhushan.extreme-advice.com/user-roles-and-permissions-in-ssrs/

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2793/sql-server-reporting-services-2012-permissions/